# Direct X: How to display an image loaded in a texture?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, directx

I'm new to DirectX and have been reading tons of tutorials and samples, however I'm unable to find any documentation on how to directly display an image that is loaded into a `Texture2D` on the screen. Almost all tutorials I've seen deal with 3D graphics, shaders, etc. However, I just want to display the contents of the texture.

Here's what I have so far:

**DeviceResources.cpp**:

```
#include "DeviceResources.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

DeviceResources::DeviceResources()
{

}


HRESULT DeviceResources::CreateDeviceResources(HWND hwnd)
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1
    };

    UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_desc;
    ZeroMemory(&swap_chain_desc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    swap_chain_desc.Windowed = TRUE;
    swap_chain_desc.BufferCount = 2;
    swap_chain_desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM;

    swap_chain_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swap_chain_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swap_chain_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    swap_chain_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
    swap_chain_desc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> swapChain;

    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        flags,
        levels,
        ARRAYSIZE(levels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swap_chain_desc,
        swapChain.GetAddressOf(),
        device.GetAddressOf(),
        &m_feature_level,
        context.GetAddressOf()
    );

    device.As(&m_device);
    context.As(&m_context);
    swapChain.As(&m_swapChain);

    cv::directx::ocl::initializeContextFromD3D11Device(m_device.Get());

    auto hdr = Renderer::HDRMetadata();
    m_swapChain->SetHDRMetaData(DXGI_HDR_METADATA_TYPE_HDR10, sizeof(DXGI_HDR_METADATA_HDR10), &hdr);
    m_swapChain->SetColorSpace1(DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G2084_NONE_P2020);

    m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), static_cast<void**>(& m_backBuffer));
    m_backBuffer->GetDesc(&m_bbDesc);

    ZeroMemory(&m_viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    m_viewport.Height = static_cast<float>(m_bbDesc.Height);
    m_viewport.Width = static_cast<float>(m_bbDesc.Width);

    m_viewport.MinDepth = 0;
    m_viewport.MaxDepth = 1;

    m_context->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);
    m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(m_backBuffer.Get(), nullptr, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf());

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DeviceResources::ConfigureBackBuffer()
{
    m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), static_cast<void**>(& m_backBuffer));
    m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(m_backBuffer.Get(), nullptr, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf());

    m_backBuffer->GetDesc(&m_bbDesc);

    ZeroMemory(&m_viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    m_viewport.Height = static_cast<float>(m_bbDesc.Height);
    m_viewport.Width = static_cast<float>(m_bbDesc.Width);

    m_viewport.MinDepth = 0;
    m_viewport.MaxDepth = 1;

    m_context->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DeviceResources::ReleaseBackBuffer()
{
    m_renderTargetView.Reset();
    m_backBuffer.Reset();

    m_context->Flush();

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DeviceResources::SetFullscreen(bool fullscreen)
{
    m_swapChain->SetFullscreenState(fullscreen, nullptr);
    ReleaseBackBuffer();

    m_swapChain->ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
    ConfigureBackBuffer();

    return S_OK;
}

void DeviceResources::Present()
{
    m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
}

DeviceResources::~DeviceResources()
= default;
```

**Renderer.cpp:**

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include <utility>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <vector>


Renderer::Renderer(std::shared_ptr<DeviceResources> resources) : m_resources(std::move(resources)), m_frameCount(0)
{
    m_frameCount = 0;
}

HRESULT Renderer::CreateDeviceDependentResources()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Renderer::CreateWindowSizeDependentResources()
{
    return S_OK;
}

void Renderer::Update()
{
    //
}

void Renderer::Render()
{
    cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("C:/Users/Richard/Downloads/orig_cave_L.ppm", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
    cv::Mat as4channelMat(mat.size(), CV_MAKE_TYPE(mat.depth(), 4));

    int conversion[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, -1, 3 };
    cv::mixChannels(&mat, 1, &as4channelMat, 1, conversion, 4);

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.Width = 3840;
    desc.Height = 2160;
    desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.BindFlags = 0;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;

    ID3D11Texture2D* tex = nullptr;

    auto hr = m_resources->GetDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &tex);

    if FAILED(hr)
    {
        _com_error err(hr);
        auto errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    }

    try {
        cv::directx::convertToD3D11Texture2D(as4channelMat, tex);
    } catch (cv::Exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.msg << std::endl;
        throw e;
    }

auto hr3 = m_resources->m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(tex.Get(), nullptr, m_texture.GetAddressOf());

    if FAILED(hr3)
    {
        _com_error err(hr3);
        auto errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> m_spriteBatch;
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 m_screenPos, m_origin;

    m_spriteBatch = std::make_unique<DirectX::SpriteBatch>(m_resources->m_context.Get());

    CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC catDesc;
    tex->GetDesc(&catDesc);

    m_origin.x = float(catDesc.Width / 2);
    m_origin.y = float(catDesc.Height / 2);

    m_screenPos.x = m_resources->m_bbDesc.Width / 2.f;
    m_screenPos.y = m_resources->m_bbDesc.Height / 2.f;

    m_spriteBatch->Begin();

    m_spriteBatch->Draw(
        m_texture.Get(), 
        m_screenPos, 
        nullptr, 
        DirectX::Colors::White, 
        0.0f, 
        m_origin
    );

    m_spriteBatch->End();
}

DXGI_HDR_METADATA_HDR10 Renderer::HDRMetadata()
{
//
}


Renderer::~Renderer()
{

}
```

From my understand, I have to somehow create a "Quad", apply the texture to it, and then display the quad itself. However,I am unsure how to do any of this and can't find any resources to help.

**Edit**: Given the recommendations, I have tried using DirectXTK, specifically `SpriteBatch`. I followed the relevant instructions in the documentation, however `Draw` doesn't seem to do / display anything. (In `Renderer.cpp`)

Comment: The *tons of tutorials* you mention did not tell you how to render geometry? Most tutorials start with a triangle. A quad can be made out of two triangles. Putting a texture on top of it is a bit more advanced but should also be covered by most tutorials. And you still need shaders. There is no way around them.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Do you happen to have any links?

Comment: E.g. [this one](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-5).

Comment: See the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)'s ``SpriteBatch`` which makes it super easy.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Ok so I'm trying to use that now and I'm following the documentation, however `Draw` isn't working? (see my edit)

Comment: My recommendation is you follow the details on the [tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) exactly first through "Sprites & Textures", get that working, and then figure out how your code differs. You have a lot of stuff going on in that code that's potentially buggy, and with graphics your best bet is to start small and add incrementally.

Comment: Also note that HDR10 on PC is a bit more complicated than your code is dealing with. The DirectX Tool Kit tutorials and my version of DeviceResources include dealing with HDR and HDR10 output.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thank you so much! I'll do that! Also, what do you mean by 'your' version of DeviceResources?

Comment: The one in [this template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/tree/master/d3d11game_win32_dr) which is used by the DirectX Tool Kit tutorial. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources) for more information.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Ok so the basic template works, however when I follow the guide to enable HDR, the window is just black

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196434/discussion-between-richard-robinson-and-chuck-walbourn).